# slight voltage reduction

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

I am powering a circuit on 4 AA batteries. 6v is not going to hurt the circuit, but it runs more optimally at 5v.  Is there a simple and effective way to drop the supply voltage by 1v to get the best results?

Comment: (1) Buck converter.  (2) Low dropout linear regulator, LDO for short.  (by the way) How much current?

Comment: Is there any 1N400X diode laying around ?

Comment: Diode or two in series.

Comment: 4AA batteries only give 6V when they are fresh - as they run down the voltage will drop to about 3.6v-4v when they are exhausted. You can use a buck-boost converter or one arrangement I used was a boost to give 6v the an LDO to give 5v. Use three cells and boost to 5v can also work.

Comment: The are various current requirements throughout the circuit, but nothing over 100mA.  I'm going to use Lithium Ion batteries which have far less of a taper-off factor than alkaline batteries.  I'll look at incorporating a TLV760 LDO.  If that proves impractical, I'll add a diode or two.  Thanks for the tips!!

Comment: What is the nominal current your circuit draws from battery? Upto what voltage your circuit can operate?

Comment: Nominally, about 80mA and 6v is the high end.  The active components are just a bunch of LEDs and an ATTiny processor.  Looking at voltage regulators, I think that the LP2950 might be a good option.  I don't think I can easily solder something as tiny as the TLV760.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer.

Here is one [low dropout linear regulator](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1185ff.pdf?domain=www.linear.com).

If you can see from data sheet, up to 1 A of load current, the dropout across the regulator will be less than 0.5 V.. It is the minimum drop which will happen.

Hence even if input is 6V ish, still the output will be strong 5 V.

I would still recommend to look at linear regulator though you mention you are using a battery for its simplicity.

But be aware that there are circuits which can give battery better mileage but it depends on

- load current
- Minimum voltage your circuit can operate
- and price target or size target
- noise over power line accepted etc

I will update my answer if you share more specific data.

A BAV720 diode for example drops easily about 0.7 V at a few 10s of mA providing you the required 5V.. Again it depends on how much tolerance your Circuit has for the fluctuation in the voltage.

Please also consider how long you need to run the circuit with batteries? What I'd the batteries drop down to 1.2 V? Then only 4.8 V will be available.

For 80 mA of load current, I would say the power lost across the regulator is negligible.

Edit 2:
Also consider running system down to 3 V.. You can find LEDs too for that range and you can also benefit from maximum juice out of the batteries. ATTiny can run down till 1.8 V /2.5 V.. Then best fit will be a buck regulator.